# Stacked divs won't stop overlapping when overflowing

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, carousel, svelte

I am trying to vertically stack several divs, each with the full height of the parent, to create a carousel-like system. Think of the container div as a viewport through which the divs within the carousel (that I want to be stacked) can be seen.
I want the inner divs can be of any size in the scroll direction (so in my case, they can be of any height, as the carousel scrolling is vertical).

My implementation is below, using SvelteKit:

```html
<div class="flex flex-col overflow-y-scroll h-full justify-start hide-scrollbar">
    {#each pages as page}
        <div class="min-h-full">
            <svelte:component this={page.component} />
        </div>
    {/each}
</div>
```

This successfully stacks the divs, but any inner divs that overflow the width of the parent (ie height > 100%), overlap with their neighbouring divs, and appear centred (some overlaps with the prior div and some with the next div).
Obviously introducing the class overflow-y-clip into each inner div stops any overlapping, but I want all the content to show without any overlapping.

How can I make the stacking work, such that each inner div, regardless of height, shows fully and does not overlap with neighbours? No scroll snapping is required.

Just some context - the reason for fitting all of this in a container div that acts as a smaller viewport is to allow for easy controlling of the content within the inner divs - it allows the use of units such as %, for example.